# How to pass data to its children in tree data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree, tree-traversal

How to traverse this tree data structure passing value to its children in javascript. Percentage is use to split the value pass to "N" and "Y"

Here's image for example [image]

Comment: can you please explain the logic to divide the values in between Y & N

Comment: @Narayan How much the percent in the circle that would go to Y and the other is to N. Example If 50% of 1000 is 500 this would go to Y and the other 50% would go to N

Comment: @Narayan Sorry I made a mistake from the image example, I updated it now.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What part of the image is the input and what part is the output you expect? What is the JavaScript data structure (can you provide the object in JavaScript notation for that image).

Comment: You speak of a tree, and tag this question with `tree`, but the graph in the image is not a tree, since there are two distinct paths from the root node to the rightmost leaf. So, what are the restrictions on this graph? Is it a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)?

Comment: Also, what does the percentage mean when there are no outgoing branches, like the node that has 30%?

Comment: @trincot The tree is generated from the that graph, Yup its a DAG. The percentage is use to split the data(100, 500, 100, 52, etc) that going to pass next circle.

Comment: What is the js datastructure? What is expected output? What does the 30% mean? What is the problem? You did not answer most of my questions.

Comment: @trincot My issue is how could I loop or traverse the tree passing the value down to the last child

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data structure, I will propose one using a Node class which has as properties:

- a fraction (the percentage as a number between 0 and 1),
- two child node references (one for "no", and one for "yes"), and
- a value which first is 0 but gets determined once the calculation has been done.

The algorithm would be a recursive one, where you start with the root and input 1000 to it. That node will apply the fraction to that value (i.e. multiply), and add the result to its own value. This value is then recursively input to the "yes" child (if there is one), and the remaining value is recursively input to the "no" child.

It is important to *add* the value to the node's existing value, as some nodes may get input from multiple "parents", as is the case in the right side of the example graph. These multiple inputs should be added up.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(fraction) {
        this.fraction = fraction; // number between 0 and 1
        this.no = null; // child node for edge with label "N"
        this.yes = null; // child node for edge with label "Y"
        this.value = 0; // This will get a value later, as input is cascaded through the graph
    }
    setChildren(no, yes) {
        this.no = no;
        this.yes = yes;
    }
    addInput(value) {
        const addedValue = value * this.fraction;
        this.value += addedValue;
        if (value) { // dripple down the value through the outward edges
            if (this.no) this.no.addInput(value - addedValue);
            if (this.yes) this.yes.addInput(addedValue);
        }
    }
}

// Create vertices with their percentages (fractions)
const nodes = [
    new Node(1),
    new Node(0.5),
    new Node(0.8),
    new Node(1),
    new Node(0.13),
    new Node(0.5),
    new Node(1),
    new Node(0.3)
];

// Create edges
nodes[0].setChildren(null, nodes[1]);
nodes[1].setChildren(nodes[2], nodes[5]);
nodes[2].setChildren(nodes[3], nodes[4]);
nodes[4].setChildren(null, nodes[5]);
nodes[5].setChildren(nodes[6], nodes[7]);

// Send a value of 1000 to the root node
nodes[0].addInput(1000);

// Show the value of each node after this action
console.log("node  value");
for (const node of nodes) {
    console.log((node.fraction*100 + "%").padStart(4), node.value.toFixed(1).padStart(6));
}
```

#### Some remarks

Although this question talks about a tree datastructure, and is tagged with `tree` and `tree-traversal`, the input graph is not a tree, but a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

It is mentioned in comments that the percentage value is used to split the value that is going to the *next* circle, but in the graph the percentage is applied to the node *itself* also: the leaf with percentage 30% receives a value of 276, but yet the image shows the node's value has the 30% applied to it.